# Is there a way to reduce this polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The following cubic polynomial $P(x)$ goes through the points $(x_0, y_0), (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3)$:

$P(x)=\frac{y_0(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)}{(x_0-x_1)(x_0-x_2)(x_0-x_3)}+\frac{y_1(x-x_0)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)}{(x_1-x_0)(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)}+\frac{y_2(x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_3)}{(x_2-x_0)(x_2-x_1)(x_2-x_3)}+\frac{y_3(x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)}{(x_3-x_0)(x_3-x_1)(x_3-x_2)}$

Is there a reasonable way to put this polynomial into the form

$$P(x)=a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$$

so the coefficients $a_i$ are in terms of the parameters $x_i$ and $y_i$? I don't have many CAS softwares, the one from geogebra gives me an incredibly ugly result and I can't even put the whole expression into the free version of wolfram, so any suggestions?

Note: one of my classmates says he simplified that expression "by hand", is that possible?

Comment: You could start by writing $P(x)=a_0+a_1 x+a_2 x^2+a_3 x^3$ and solved the system $P(x_i)=y_i,\,i=0,1,2,3$ with respect to the $a_i$. I'm sure this can be eine by hand and also by using some CAS.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a reasonable way

That depends on how reasonable you consider "reasonable". For example, you could combine all the fractions so that they're over the common denominator $(x_1-x_0)(x_2-x_0)(x_3-x_0)(x_2-x_1)(x_3-x_1)(x_3-x_2)$ and then multiply out whatever you get on top. There might be a better way, but I don't know of it.

> the one from geogebra gives me an incredibly ugly result

The result probably *is* ugly. (Have you tried doing this for e.g. a quadratic or even a linear polynomial? I'd be willing to bet that's probably ugly too.)

> one of my classmates says he simplified that expression "by hand", is that possible?

Sure, it's possible. It's not even conceptually difficult - it's just really long and tedious.